# PrimeFaces not fully rendering my components

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

PrimeFaces is not rendering. I have configured everything correctly (hope so).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:mp="http://primefaces.org/ui/material">
    <head>
<title>Welcome Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h:head>
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="5">
                    <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Name:" style="font-weight:bold" />
                    <p:inputText id="name" value="#{basicView.text}" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="display"
                        icon="ui-icon-check" />
                    <h:outputText id="display" value="#{basicView.text}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </h:head>
    </body>
</ui:composition>
```

```java
public class BasicView {

    private String text;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

I have included all the annotations and lib.

[Here is the Index.xhtml output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7CNT.png)

Answer (score 2):

You messed up the head and body tags. Also you need to put your form in the body.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<h:html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:mp="http://primefaces.org/ui/material">
    <h:head>
        <title>Welcome Page</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="5">
                <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Name:" style="font-weight:bold" />
                <p:inputText id="name" value="#{basicView.text}" />
                <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="display"
                    icon="ui-icon-check" />
                <h:outputText id="display" value="#{basicView.text}" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</h:html>
```

Comment: I always wonder what tutorial is used when this kind of xhtml is created. We should file a 'removal' with google so no-one can run into this ascwell